# How to control service account display name in Google Admin Domain-wide Delegation?

Tags: google-workspace

I am facing an issue with the **client name** displayed in [Google Admin > Security > API controls > Domain-wide Delegation](https://admin.google.com/u/1/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation).

Let's say I have created a service account on [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts):

[image: service account details]

When I authorize a scope for that service account on Google Admin side (different workspace), the name displayed doesn't match anything I have typed:

[image: service account displayed name]

For the record, this `M      Connector` descriptor was used before for another service account in the same Google Project (or another project of same Google Workspace, don't remember exactly), but clearly today I don't have any service account matching this in my Google Project.

Is there a way to control the name displayed in Google Admin Domain-wide Delegation list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Client Name that is displayed in your Domain-wide delegation is actually the name of your App in your Oauth Consent Screen.

[image]

### my service account:

[image]

### my domain-wide delegation:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have a different "Name" by "Client ID"? For security reasons we have multiple service-accounts each with very specific purpose (e.g. 1 just for Gmail use, 1 just for Gdocs, etc.)